# Why does sender IP address increment in Scapy?

Tags: python, networking, logic, scapy

I am trying to make a TCP packet that is sent to my other computer 500 times. I have created this code:

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.utils import rdpcap
#Create your own packets
data = 'This is a test'
myPacket = Ether(src="00:E0:4C:00:02:42",dst="00:E0:4C:01:08:99")/IP(src="169.254.162.71/16",dst="169.254.208.208/16")/TCP()/Raw(load=data)
print(myPacket.show())
for i in range (0,500):
    sendp(myPacket, iface="Ethernet 4")  # sending packet at layer 2
```

The issue is that when I run this code, the computer receives packets with an incrementing Source IP and the Destination IP is wrong, for some reason:

[image]

Any help fixing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/16` in your addresses is called a netmask in CIDR notation. It means that your adresses are subnets that include all possible addresses between `169.254.0.0` and `169.254.255.255`. (Same for the source IP)
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Scapy is going to send 256x256x256x256 (accounting for both `sr` and `dst`) packets with all possible addresses, starting as you saw with the `0.0` ones. You just need to remove the `/16`.